# MasterMind in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have an assignment from my school in which we have to make a MasterMind game in C# in a console application.

So far I managed to do the border (with help from friends), an introductory tune (beep) when the game starts, and the user input to insert the numbers.

The problem is when the user ends the game, the game doesn't stop to accept inputs from the user and obviously crashes.

I also have an error in the high score method "use of unassigned local variable".

Comment: Please read [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/140505). You have posted way too much.

Comment: Expanding on what Oded is saying, you will have better luck if your questions and code examples are more pointed.  I would start by searching for specific errors, for example, what "use of unassigned local variable" means.  If you can't find the answer, then post a question regarding it, using only the block of code that is producing the error.

Comment: You could try commenting out your error handlers, and then debug in visual studio - it'll show you which line the exception occurs on. Try asking your teacher for help anyway - that's what they're there for. If you don't understand the syntax, a particular method or datatype - it's as simple as googling to find tonnes of example code and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

```
score = ptsguesses * ptsTime;
```

Where are ptsguesses and ptsTime initialized? Nowhere, obviously.

You probably want to set ptsguesses and ptsTime *before* calculating the score.

Answer (score 0):

the use of unassigned value is probably this one:

```
 static void highscore()
    {
        {
            byte ptsguesses,ptsTime, userGuesses, timeTaken;
            int score; <<------
```

change it to int score = 0;

also, ptsguesses,ptstime,userguesses and timetaken have never been initialised.
you might want to try to pass those arguments to your highscore() method.

something like

```
static void highscore(byte ptsguesses, byte ptsTime, byte userGuesses, byte timeTaken)
```

you'd have to call the highscore() method then, and pass the actual values to the method. that way if u try to run highscore(), you will have something to actually calculate.

Comment: OK im a bit confused do I do this or byte userchoice = 1; or both?

Comment: well as you said yourself, by doing byte userchoice = 1, nothing happens. That's kinda normal, because you are passing the value "1" to userchoice, where it should be some actual value coming from the game. doing it my way you could achieve that.